# Wondering how to translate imperfect subjunctives (in a conditional sentence)

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, conjunctive, conditions

I have to translate this sentence for homework:

> *si verba patris a liberis non audita essent, timerent.*

I believe the verb form in both the protasis and apodosis is imperfect subjunctive. I am really struggling trying to work out how to put this into english. This is what I've got so far (I know that the tense/aspect is not correct):

> If the words from the books of the father would not be heard, they might have been afraid.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 'Books' would be in the abl. pl. _libris_. Here we have _a liberis_, 'children'.

Comment: Also, note that verb in the protasis is audita essent, not just essent. So the tense in that clause isn't actually imperfect.

Comment: 'If the father's words had not been heard by his children (back then), they would be afraid (now).'